# What is this portion of The Algorithm Design Manual saying? I'm confused

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, complexity-theory, time-complexity

This is from The Algorithm Design Manual when talking about Dictionaries being implemented with Linked Lists.

[image]

For one, with the portion that says "on insertion check whether `last->next` still equals NULL`. Why would we have to check that? If I'm inserting an element, how would that affect whether or not the last item rightfully points to NULL? If we're doing our implementations correctly, shouldn't it already? Couldn't we just say something like:

```
last->next = nodeToInsert;
last = last->next;
```

Why wouldn't that work?

Secondly, is the second last paragraph talking about the case where we delete the last item in a singly-linked list and have to identify the new last item? And that we'd just (with O(n) complexity) traverse to the second last item and set that to last and delete the former last? And we mix this with the pre-existing delete method, just adding a case for if it's the last item?

Answer (score 3):

> Why would we have to check that?

Because presumably you're not always inserting at the end of the list, so `last` doesn't always need to be updated.

> Secondly, ...

Yes.

Comment: If you're not inserting at the end, what would be the practicality of checking if `last->next` equals `NULL`? If I'm inserting an item (into what I can only assume this is referencing is a sorted Linked List) and it's to go in the middle, wouldn't it start at the beginning and traverse forward until it finds the proper location? (Given that Binary Search is not possible with Linked Lists.) Then wouldn't we only need to deal with the last item if it's greater than it? And why would we have to check if it's NULL? It should always be null, what else would it point to? It's the last...

Comment: You don't know on insertion whether or not you've inserted at the end.  You have to check after the insertion to see where the element ended up - or, more simply, to see whether or not it ended up at the end, thus making it the new maximum.  Remember `last` is whatever the last element was before the insertion, so if `(*last).next` (I dislike the -> notation) is still NULL, then that means it's still the end of the list; if `(*last).next` is not NULL, then there is another element now at the end of the list, meaning there is a new maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this section is talking about dictionaries being implemented as *sorted* lists.

This means that the insertion needs to happen at exactly the right point.
Your suggested code adds to the end of the list:

```
last->next = nodeToInsert;
last = last->next;
```

This would be correct for unsorted lists, but not for sorted.

Also note that the author is using last as a pointer that is additional to the normal linked list.

I think you believe that last is part of the doubly linked list structure.  If this were so, then you would be correct that it should have been updated during the insertion.  However, as it is an independent pointer, the additional code described in the text is required to keep it consistent with the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(last->next != NULL) {   // insertion occurred at the tail end
    last = nodeToInsert;   // so update tail pointer to point to inserted node
}
```

The tail end insertion has set `last->next` already. It is no longer `NULL` because of the insertion. That is what tells us that `last` needs to be updated (`last` is now actually `lastButOne`). If `last->next` is still `NULL` then we don't need to do anything because the insertion occurred somewhere before `last`. The wording of your book is, perhaps, slightly misleading. Does this make sense now?